# Redirecting short http URL to main https domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I bought a short domain name so i can share short urls like

```
http://xxx.xx/itemID
```

i've configured the short domain DNS to point to my server, now i'm editing the apache site conf and im not sure is correct procedure:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName xxx.xx 
    ServerAlias www.xxx.xx
    Redirect / https://longname.xx/
</VirtualHost>
```

basically I want this:

> http://xxx.xx/itemID  ==>  https://longname.xx/itemID

what else do i have to do? how to edit the `htaccess` now?

Comment: You `Redirect` rule should work in `VirtualHost` config. Make sure you restart your Apache after above change.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```